# Which Xeon processors have hardware support for H.265 encoding/decoding?

Tags: video-encoding, xeon, h.265

Looking to build a rendering machine for H.265 video: would I be better off with a Core i7/i9 because of built-in hardware accelerated H.265 encoding/decoding, or can Xeon processors support it as well? If so, which ones?

Comment: If this is for serious work (especially with a lot of different simultaneous encodings) you need GPU(s).

Comment: Intel's HEDT processors (including *Skylake-X*) do not have integrated graphics processors and cannot accelerate video encoding. Get a GeForce 10 Series or Quadro P-series card instead; even the GT 1030 can do HEVC.

Answer (score 1):

**Generational Implementations of HEVC (H.265)**

Since consumers expect you to optimize your media applications for all types of devices, it’s important to look at the capabilities of the recent generations of Intel processors.

- 4th Generation Intel Core processors (Haswell CPU 2- 3.5GHz, 4
  Cores): Includes an HEVC Software Decoder capable of real time decode
  of HEVC 4K streams.
- 5th Generation Intel Core processors (Broadwell): Supports HEVC 8-bit
  software/hybrid encode.
- **6th Generation Intel Core processors (Skylake) Supports hardware
  accelerated HEVC 8-bit decode and encode**.

[Source](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/12/11/codecs-are-they-slowing-you-down)

Several dozen Xeon processors fall in these categories, all 6th Gen [Skylake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#Skylake-based_Xeons) and the newer 7th Gen [Kaby Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Xeon_microprocessors#Kaby_Lake-based_Xeons) based Xeon processors have hardware encode/decode support.

Comment: -1. The OP's looking at HEDT processors ("Core i7/i9") which don't have an IGP and can't accelerate video encoding.

Comment: What does that even mean that a CPU includes an HEVC __Software__ Decoder?